# TypeError Cannot access offset of type string on string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\xtendanceweb\resources\views\laporan\index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

Can some one help me with this problem?
my error : TypeError
Cannot access offset of type string on string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\xtendanceweb\resources\views\laporan\index.blade.php)

my code in controller

```
 if(isset($request->filter_date)) {
            $date_start = Carbon::parse($request->filter_date)->format('Y-m-d');
            $date_end = Carbon::parse($request->end_date)->format('Y-m-d');

 $company_holiday = CompanyHoliday::where('company_holiday.company_id', $company_id)
            ->whereDateBetween('company_holiday.date', $date_start, $date_end)
            ->get();
 }
```

my code in index.blade.php

```
   @foreach($company_holiday as $comp_hol)
        @php
             $company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;

                  if($comp_hol != null){
                       $holiday = array_filter(json_decode($comp_hol, true), function ($var) use ($company_id) {
                              return $var['company_id'] == $company_id;
                       });

                  }else{
                        $comp_hol = null; 
                  }
         @endphp
   @endforeach
```

Comment: At some point `json_decode($comp_hol, true)` returns a string meaning that `$comp_hol` is a JSON encoded string rather than a JSON object

Answer (score 0):

At one point `$var` is a string. You can solve that problem by checking it is an array and it contains the `'company_id'` key:

```
return is_array($var) && isset($var['company_id']) && $var['company_id'] == $company_id;
```

I don't know the contents of the json, so it could be that this will never return true.